# How to decrease performance of a browser to test a heavy angular application to emulate a low config pc?

Tags: angular, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cpu-usage

I have an Angular and Nodejs application running on a Intel i7 8th gen 16GB ram. But recently on one of my colleague's laptop it had stuck(got a **Page Un-responsive** pop-up on chrome) on one of the webpage after performing some actions and its configuration was Intel i3 4th gen 4GB ram. Now I want to test that same scenario on my side to fix that performance issue.

I have seen that this occurs due to HEAVY CPU utilization. So if somehow I am able to limit cpu usage then it will throw that page unresponsive error popup. How to achieve this?

How to reduce chrome browser's performance?

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/

Answer (score 2):

You can use google chrome's developer's tool in order to decrease your CPU power
Just open the developer's tool and in the `performance` tab, click on the setting gear button, and then in the CPU select box you can slow down your CPU up to 6 times.

[image]